# How to download specific version of war file from nexus using Ansible

Tags: maven, ansible, nexus

I have different version of war file present in my Nexus repository.

[image]

Below is my ansible code

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: True
  tasks:
    - name: Download war file
      maven_artifact:
        group_id: in.flex
        artifact_id: halosys
        repository_url: 'http://34.239.122.5:8081/repository/halosys-release/'
        username: admin
        password: xxxxx
        dest: /tmp/
```

Please let me know the syntax to download specific version of war file like **halosys-1.0.war, halosys-5.0.war** in Ansible

Comment: If there is a parameter for groupId and artifact, isn't there one for version as well?

Comment: How to change my Ansible code to download specific version of war file ?

Comment: Was this an answer to my question?

Comment: No, I am asking please provide me the ansible code to achieve my requirement

Comment: But you already asked that in the question itself. Have you checked whether there is a `version` parameter ?

Comment: After adding version parameter its worked thanks a lot JF Meier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- name: "Download war file"
  maven_artifact:
    group_id: in.flex
    artifact_id: halosys
    extension: war
    version: 5.0
    repository_url: "http://34.239.122.5:8081/repository/halosys-release/"
    username: admin
    password: xxxxx
    dest: "/tmp/ROOT.war"
    mode: '0644'
```

source : https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/maven_artifact_module.html#examples

it's better to have vars file and use jinja

exemple

```
...
version: "{{ versions.halosys }}"
...
```

Comment: Be careful about using `version: 5.0` since yaml will coerce that into a floating point number; ideally quote it just like you did with your jinja2 follow-up example